# How can i pass filter for a API rest like WHERE field = 'value'?

Tags: php, rest, api

I want to pass filter to it for get, for example, one single row based on this filters but i don't know how to do that.

```
<?php
namespace app\Model
{
    class RestFull
    {
        private $url = 'http://myurl.azurewebsites.net/tables/';
        private $curl;
        private $response;
        private $table;

        public function __construct(){}

        /**
         * Start the API RestFull
         * ---- ~ ----
         */
        public function apiRest($table, $id = null)
        {
            $this->table = $table;
            $this->setUrl($id);
            $this->initCurl();
            $this->setHeader();
        }   

        /**
         * Get data from API
         * Method GET
         */
        public function restGet()
        {
            $this->response = curl_exec($this->curl);
            $this->getErrors();
            curl_close($this->curl);
        }

        /**
         * Post data for API
         * Method POST
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function restPost(array $data)
        {
            $data = json_encode($data);
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $this->response = curl_exec($this->curl);
            $this->getErrors();
            curl_close($this->curl);
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        public function restPut()
        {

        }       

        /**
         *
         */
        public function restDelete()
        {

        }

        /**
         * Return the response
         * @return json
         */
        public function setResponse()
        {
            return $this->response;
        }

        /**
         * Generate the url value
         */
        private function setUrl($id = null)
        {
            $id = (!empty($id) ? "/{$id}" : null);
            $this->url = $this->url . $this->table . $id;
        }

        /**
         * Init Curl
         * ---- 1 ----
         */
        private function initCurl()
        {
            $this->curl = curl_init($this->url);
        }

        /**
         * Set headers
         * ---- 2 ----
         */
        private function setHeader()
        {
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['zumo-api-version: 2.0.0', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        }

        /**
         * Errors
         * @return string
         */
        private function getErrors()
        {
            if($this->curl === false):
                curl_close($this->curl);
                return 'An error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export(curl_getinfo($this->curl));
            endif;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a REST server, or a client?
If client, depends on what the server supports. Could be post values:

```
$data = array(
     "key" => "value"
);

curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

or could be appending to the string to the URL:

```
?api_key=civicrm123
```

If server, you'll need to bind the query to the model, to filter the result when the query runs to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. See the image below. Can you give me an example of format for fill this $filter field, for example? http://www.programacaocriativa.com.br/stackoverflow.png

Comment: Without knowing what platform you are writing to, every API would have its own rules, etc. If it is Azure, then it seems you can use language in the constructs i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/azure/dn798921.aspx -> filter=baseRate lt 100.0 and rating ge 4  . In that case, you would append the query to the URL with the values based on their documentation. Personally, I would write a test.php script with the CURL stuff, and run until the post works. I've found with MYOB and GeoOps API that syntax can be quite sensitive to case and other characters that aren't mentioned in docs.